# Pressing on the notification removes alertDialog

Tags: android, notifications, android-alertdialog

i have a "wierd" problam.
i made an alertdialog that appers whan the bluetooth is connected, also made anotification that states it so you'll now it whan the app is in the background.
whan the bluetooth connects while im inside the app every thing is good.
also whan the app is in the backgroung (when notification sound) and i press on the app icon (on the launcher) or pressing on the "last used". all ok.
but if the app is in the backgound (when notification sound) and i press on the notification to luanch the app, the alertdialog disappears.  and reappears when i press the back button...
i couldnt find why.
i need your help to try and direct me to fix problam.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problam.  when you press the notification it created a duplicat activity... when you press the icon it goes to the onresume..  so i added android:launchMode="singleInstance" the the manifast under the activity and it works... hope it help anyone.